# Drawing Image in centre while maintaining the Aspect Ratio

Tags: c++, gdi+

Part 1 : In one of my projects, I want to display a Image in center of a Custom Control using GDI+ while maintaining the aspect ratio of the Image. Here is my code

```
Gdiplus::Image image(imagePathWStr); // imagePathWStr is the Image Path

int originalWidth = image.GetWidth();
int originalHeight = image.GetHeight();

// This code calculates the aspect ratio in which I have to draw the image
int16 cntrlwidth = controlPosition.right - controlPosition.left;  // controlPosition is the custom Control Rect
int16 cntrlheigth = controlPosition.bottom - controlPosition.top;
float percentWidth = (float)cntrlwidth / (float)originalWidth;
float percentHeight = (float)cntrlheigth / (float)originalHeight;

float percent = percentHeight < percentWidth ? percentHeight : percentWidth;

int newImageWidth = (int)(originalWidth * percent);
int newImageHeight = (int)(originalHeight * percent);

Gdiplus::RectF imageContainer;
imageContainer.X = controlPosition.left;
imageContainer.Y = controlPosition.top;
imageContainer.Width = controlPosition.right;
imageContainer.Height = controlPosition.bottom;

Gdiplus::Graphics gdiGraphics(hDC);
Gdiplus::Unit scrUnit = Gdiplus::UnitPixel;
gdiGraphics.DrawImage(&image, imageContainer, 0, 0, originalWidth, originalHeight, scrUnit);
```

However when the Control is resized vertically the image is moving to the right and not always stay in center, Also when Control is resized Horizontally, it is moving to the bottom. I am not able to figure out why.
I am using C++ on Windows.

Part 2: Now I have got a Rectangle drawn as well on top of this

```
Gdiplus::RectF cropRect;
cropRect.X = 100;
cropRect.Y = 100;
cropRect.Width = 300;
cropRect.Height = 300;

Gdiplus::Pen* myPen = new Gdiplus::Pen(Gdiplus::Color::White);
myPen->SetWidth(3);
gdiGraphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, cropRect);
```

Now When I resize the Control, Image is getting resized correctly but this rectangle is not, I multiplied Width and Height accordingly

```
Gdiplus::RectF cropRectangle;
cropRectangle.X = cropRect.GetLeft();
cropRectangle.Y = cropRec.GetTop();
cropRectangle.Width = (cropRec.Width)* percent;
cropRectangle.Height = (cropRec.Height ) * percent;
```

My Part 1 has been solved after Adrians Answer now I am stuck on Part 2 of my problems

Thanks

-Pankaj

Comment: Shouldn't `imageContainer.Width` be `controlPosition.right - controlPosition.left`?  (And similarly for Height.)

Comment: Thanks @AdrianMcCarthy. Yes, That was a silly mistake on my part. :(

Answer (score 0):

when the size of the control changes you'll have a WM_SIZE message posted to your window. you must refresh your aspect ratio according to new size.